# InvoiceNo to print with the 2 zeros of count

Tags: java, text-files

I have this code but I want the `InvoiceNo` to print with the 2 zeros of count.  How can I do this?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
int count= 001;
String InvoiceNo= "INV" + count++;
System.out.println(InvoiceNo);
}
```

I also want to print this to a text file and every time have the previous InvoiceNo to be increased by 001 eg INV001 then the next one INV002 then INV003 etc. but next time I open the program for it to add to the previous `InvoiceNo`.

Comment: *"I also want.."*  That is an entirely separate matter that should be asked in an entirely separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int count =1; count <1000; count ++ ){
        String InvoiceNo= "INV" + String.format("%03d",count);
        System.out.println(InvoiceNo);
}
```

run that and see if it gets the desired output that you want. I think it does. In anycase,

`String InvoiceNo= "INV" + String.format("%03d",count++);`

will work for your needs.

Comment: Just use `System.out.printf(...)`

Comment: @Kevin  I don't see how `printf` could work for *naming files.*

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't see where the OP indicates he's going to use this for naming files, he wants to "print this to a text file." Regardless, as long as `String.format` is being used, the `INV` should be part of the format and not a separate `+`.

Comment: @Kevin  On reading the question again just now, it became obvious my earlier comment to you was wrong.  My bad.

Comment: The code given kind of does what I want but it prints 1000 numbers.

Comment: I was just showing you that the formatting works even after 100. You don't need the for loop all you need is the line at the end of my answer. Accept if this answer works

Answer (score 0):

```
        String InvoiceNo= "INV" + String.format("%03d",count);
        System.out.printf(InvoiceNo);
```

Comment: lol you keep answering the same questions I do after I answer them with the exact same answer as me